# Firebase Dynamic Links, not working

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to investigate Firebase Dynamic Links, at this point without much success.

I got started with this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create.
Though I followed the instruction as much as I could. I seem to hit a problem when testing:

```
https://app_code.app.goo.gl/apple-app-site-association
```

With my information typing something like the line below in the browser, in Safari (on my computer, or mailing the link to my iphone):

```
https://zy37bs.app.goo.gl/apple-app-site-association
```

I get this result:

```
{"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[]}}
```

If I test the same link in FireFox I get about seven line of garbage (starting with the same as above), but it does not seem to contain anything usable.

I have never touched Firebase Dynamic Links before. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This relates to how iOS Universal Links work. Universal Links are a protocol from Apple that Firebase uses. The URL `https://zy37bs.app.goo.gl/apple-app-site-association` is *not* a Universal Link — it is the location of a verification file required by iOS to enable Universal Links. An actual Dynamic Link (enabled for Universal Links) would look something like `https://zy37bs.app.goo.gl/my-link-slug`.

For a more conceptual overview of how Universal Links work, check out [this blog post](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9/). It won't be totally relevant in your case because Firebase takes care of the hosting components, but it should help clarify what is happening under the hood.

Comment: Thanks. It started to work in between my posting and my reading you anser, without me exactly knowing why. It may be that things take time to get set up, but I am not sure. It could also be that I changed something on the way.